# A custom login view popup like an alertview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

I am trying to make a custom login view popup like an alert view. I am simulating the alertview popup with the following function. This function is found in the viewDidload in mine loginViewController.m

```
-(void)initialDelayEnded {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);
    self.view.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0/1.5 animations:^{
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);
    }completion:^(BOOL complete){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0/2 animations:^{
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
        }completion:^(BOOL complete){
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0/2 animations:^{
                self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            }];
        }];
    }];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self initialDelayEnded];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And I'm calling in my firstViewController my loginViewController in the following way.

```
LoginViewController *login = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:NULL];
        [self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

But it crashes with the following error.

```
'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <UIView: 0x8674bf0; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x8670620>> is associated with <LoginViewController: 0x868a7d0>. Clear this association before associating this view with <LoginViewController: 0x8451e70>.
```

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Possibly `[super viewDidLoad]` should go first?

Comment: No still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have special reason, please keep `[super viewDidLoad];` call to be done as early as possible within your local implementation. Meaning: call `[self initialDelayEnded];` AFTER `[super viewDidLoad];`

Please make sure your .xib file named `LoginViewController` has only one `File's Owner` in `Placeholders` and NO ViewController object in `Objects` panels. And make sure `File's Owner`s custom class is `LoginViewController`. Can you please upload the screenshot of your .xib, specifically showing `Document Outline`? It will be much easier to figure what could have been wrong

Comment: Yes I found the answer. And the problem is exactly what you're talking about. This question helped me fix it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434937/uiviewcontrollerhierarchyinconsistency-when-trying-to-present-a-modal-view-contr

Comment: I am glad it helped. I did have same problem myself a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
[self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

you are presenting a `viewController` by Self which i guess is a `viewcontroller` itself.

instead you should use:

```
[self presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];
```

if you want to present your `viewcontroller` rather pushing it on the navigation stack.
In which class you are using this code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is still crashing with the same error.

Comment: In which class are you using this code as the error states that the view associated with LoginViewController of yours is already associated with some other viewcontroller when you call the presentViewController code;

Comment: `- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated` is Deprecated as on iOS 6

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your LoginViewController xib? Is there a possibility you are mapping the same view with more than 1 view controllers there?

Comment: Yes I checked it, but I connected my view with only one view.

Answer (score 0):

The error message implies that there are two instances of 'LogInViewController'. Are you using story boards? If so you could add the view controller to the main storyboard file (rather than a separate nib), give it a tag/identifier (but don't connect it to the other VCs). You can then grab the storyboard created instance and present that. Like so:

```
//Get the stroyboard
UIStoryBoard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryBoard storyboardWithName:<STORYBOARD_NAME> bundle:nil];

//Get the VC
LogInViewController *login = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:<VIEWCONTROLLER_TAG>];

//Present
[self presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];
```

Also, you should not try to present other view controllers in `viewDidLoad:`, it will not work. Move the code to present the new controller into `viewDidAppear:`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my apps login problem in the following way >

1. Used Alert View to show up in AppDelegate on applicationDidBecomeActive
2. Add a UIView Controller with XIB to project named LoginSubView. Kept it blank and added Tag to it say 99
3. Loaded the  LoginSubView controller before the alert box shows up.

   ```
   AFLoginViewController *LoginSubView = [[AFLoginViewController alloc] init];
   [_window addSubview:LoginSubView.view];
   [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

   UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"This is an example alert!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];
   alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput;
   [alert show];
   ```
4. If login was successful I removed the  LoginSubView just before anything else with following lines

   ```
   for (UIView *subView in _window.subviews)
   {
       if (subView.tag == 99)
       {
           [subView removeFromSuperview];
       }
   }
   ```
5. could also add the same subview on applicationDidEnterBackground as well. to avoid flicker the sensitive screen view when coming back to foreground next time