# UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency clear association

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I know this question was posted before, but answers I ´ve found are not according this case

The exception occurs after running an app wroten 2 years ago in Xcode 4.5.1.

This is:

> exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', 
>   reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! 
>   <UIView: 0xaa9c4f0; frame = (0 0; 320 367); autoresize = W+H; layer = >
>   is associated with <TabledReservationListController: 0xaa89e80>. Clear this association before associating this view with <UIViewController: 0x9e9e310>.'

Then in several answers like this one

[UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency when trying to present a modal view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434937/uiviewcontrollerhierarchyinconsistency-when-trying-to-present-a-modal-view-contr)

suggest to remove the viewcontroller in the nib file like it can be seen on the question image.

The problem is that in this case , i don´t have the viewController, this is the nib file of TabledReservationListController:

[image: TabledReservationListView.xib]

And this is the part of the code where the app crashes:

```objetive-c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [navigation setDelegate: self];
    [self createReservationListController];

    [reservationListController viewWillAppear: NO];

     // in this line below
    [[navigation topViewController] setView: [reservationListController view]];

    [reservationListController viewDidAppear: NO];

    [[self view] addSubview: [navigation view]];
    CGRect r = [[self view] frame];
    r.origin.y = 0;
    [[navigation view] setFrame: r];

    [reservationListController setNavigationController: navigation];
}


- (void)createReservationListController {
    TabledReservationListController *res_ =
        [[TabledReservationListController alloc] initWithNibName: @"TabledReservationListView"
                                                          bundle: nil];
    [self setReservationListController: res_];
    [res_ release];

    [[[self navigation] topViewController] setTitle: @"Available Tables"];
}
```

Maybe someone could help, regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.  Those are supposed to be methods where the framework calls you.

Instead of trying to give the `reservationListController`'s view to a different controller, you should push `reservationListController`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. The app is kind of complex and was coded by another person, i´m beginner in iOS. I think he tried to load different views with same structure  (TabledReservationListController) in a property of ReservationListPresenterController, which is ReservationListController. Would be grotesque if I paste all the code here because of size. The problem started with Xcode 4.5 and UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency.