# swift 3 present UIViewController: nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: ios, swift

> Update(3)

I have the following code:

This works if I wait in the debugger:

And if I dont:

> A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a
>   time!

```
@IBAction func openTestViewController(_ sender: Any) {
    let b = Bundle(identifier: "com.test")
    let m = MultipleListViewController(nibName: "MultipleListViewController", bundle: b)
    self.present(m, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This does not work; error: `

> A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a
>   time!

```
@IBAction func openTestViewController(_ sender: Any) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let b = Bundle(identifier: "com.test")
    let m = MultipleListViewController(nibName: "MultipleListViewController", bundle: b)
    self.present(m, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

Note: The reason I do `Bundle(identifier: "com.test")` is because I have it in a framework.

This only works if:
1. I set a breakpoint
2. And wait for it to load - and make sure that I can see it with the little preview eye when debugging.

How can I/should i wait for it in code?

Comment: If you remove the bundle in `MultipleListViewController ` initialization works fine?

Comment: Thanks, but no then I get: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle. Note; I am loading from a framework that I also created.

Comment: Can you try to load `MultipleListViewController` in new project and check if works separately? `"MyViewController"` exists?

Comment: Good question: I have this in a seperate project just for testing the framework. And it is strange that it do work when I just wait for it in the debugger?

Comment: Are in the main thread? What happens if you wrap the code inside `DispatchQueue.main.async {  }`? What happens if you wrap only the last line?

Comment: Then I get: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!'

Comment: Where is this code in your project? We need some more context.

Comment: What happens if you replace the second line with `let m = MultipleListViewController()` ?

Comment: @Yonat I get a black screen, meaning that it does not load the nib file.

Comment: @Giuseppe Lanza Thanks, do you need more?

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434937/uiviewcontrollerhierarchyinconsistency-when-trying-to-present-a-modal-view-contr

Comment: @Yonat Thanks already tried that.